# Read unread message in JSQMessagesViewController using Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm trying this method on button click but not get result:

```
@IBAction func childAdded(_ sender: Any) {       
    let ref = Constants.refs.databaseChats.childByAutoId()

    ref.observe(DataEventType.childAdded , with: { (snapshot) in
        let msgData = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let msg = msgData?["status"] as? String

        if msg == "sent" {
            let prntRef = Constants.refs.databaseChats.child("chats").child(ref.key)
            prntRef.updateChildValues(["status":"Read"])
            print("Message Read")
        }
    }) { (e) in
        print(e.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am really confused? I don't really understand what question you are asking. Also I don't see much of a correlation between the title and the code provided. Also am I correct in assuming you are using `firebase`. Would you mind stating a question so we can determine the best way to help you?

Comment: i want add functionality in firebaseChat App message Read Unread

Comment: if sender send the message to receiver when receiver read the message display any activityIndicator to the sender

Comment: in sort i want message status like , message seen

Comment: This is much more a `firebase` question then. JSQMessagesViewController is only a UI Library. It will enable you to show the read and unread message state but the logic for what the state of a message is, is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways of doing this and some have advantages over others. One solution would be to store a variable like `lasReadVariable` or something, in `firebase`. that is the last read message for user1 then every time the `chatView` is opened update that `lasReadVariable` for last read message on this thread. Have an `observer` for user2 in the conversation on the `lasReadVariable` and update the `messageState` accordingly.

Let me know if there is more clarification I can give.